# Custom resources within SCIM protocol

Tags: provisioning, scim

Beside of users and groups does SCIM covers CRUD operations for other resources.
I guess no ?
Mean on custom resources for specific cases. Per instance custom Product resource to be provisioned between two trusted SPs.

The only one extensibility (correct me if I am wrong) dictated by SCIM default schema is Enterprise User ("urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, only users and groups are covered by the spec, but as you mentioned you can always add extensions.

Comment: Is it possible to add extension only for User (as Enterprise User) or to extend to new resource ? If I extend it to the new resource is it still under SCIM protocol or it is then custom protocol ?

Comment: Yes, you can extend User. Yes, as long as you don't alter the API and schema semantics your implementation is SCIM compliant even after adding any number of extended resources.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.
SCIM is not only users and groups!
the RFCs are only mentioning users and groups but are defining a much wider scale of resources.
Here is a java library supporting the definition of any resource-type: https://github.com/Captain-P-Goldfish/SCIM-SDK

I personally using it especially much for administration tools that define CRUD operations for specific resources.